# (How) can I collapse commits branching out

Tags: mercurial

My revision graph looks like:

```
F
|
E
|\
| |
C |
| D
| |
B |
| |
|/
|
A
```

I want to collapse all commits from B to F into a single one. A is not mine, and I don't want to touch it. I'd like to have in the end:

```
X
|
A
```

Is this possible ? I've tried various collapse and rebase commands but could not achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with the [`mq`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension) extension for the patch queue. You will need to remove the merge changeset (since I don't think you can `qimport` a merge) and reorder the patches (which may require some hand merging of the patch file).

1. `hg qimport --rev F --name F`
2. `hg qpop`
3. `hg strip -r tip` -- this removes the merge changeset
4. `hg qimport -r C -n C`
5. `hg qpop`
6. `hg qimport -r B -n B`
7. `hg qpop`
8. `hg qimport -r D -n D` -- now you have all 4 changes (D, B, C, F) in the patch queue

At this point you can `hg qpush --all` to apply all the patches and you will need to resolve all the conflicts that result in rejected patches. This is to manually redo the work that the merge changeset `E` had previously accomplished. Once that is completed via editing and `hg qref` commands, `qpop` all the patches except for `D`.

9. `hg qfold B C F` -- this will merge the B, C, and F patches into patch D
10. `hg qfin D` -- this will convert patch D into a finalized changeset

A few more notes:

- As always, back up your work before you start (a copy of the folder is fine). You can also use your diff tools after the steps to compare the original and the result to ensure that you didn't miss anything.
- If you have pushed any of those changesets to another repo, you will need to delete them there (either with `hg strip` or changing their phase to `secret`).
- If the merge changeset `E` did a lot of work (i.e. there were conflicts between B+C and D) the extra step between 9. and 10. will be messy since your typical merge tools are not available.

---

The follow up question I have for you though: *Why? What do you hope to accomplish?* Branching and merging with smaller changesets is standard operating procedure with DVCS. After a few more changes, all those changes will scroll into history and never come up again. Worrying about a perfect history graph is really unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, finally I managed to do with rebase (D to C) + collapse once everything was linear. I had the same "problems" trying to use mq as with my previous attempts at rebase, namely that the commits were "immutable". Once I learned about the new "phases" feature (and how to change phases), I could do the rebase. My changes were not really "public", it's just that I backed up the repo before editing using cloning (so the change were only "published" in my backup).

Comment: As to "why": B and C are a code fix, and D is a unit test. I wanted to write the test and see it fail without the fix. The branching is not my usual procedure, it can be seen as a failure at TDD'ing properly in the right order.

Comment: Also, these changesets are small and I'd like to present a un-messy thing for publication (I think this is more traditional, using personal commits as save/checkpoints).

Comment: Glad you figured it out. I mostly asked because I've seen devs who were extremely focused on having a linear history and watched it turn messy (lost history and duplicated changes). Your use case as you explained it makes sense to me though! Happy coding! `:)`

Comment: I finally had time to test the mq solution. It works too so I'm accepting the answer. I must say it's much simpler with rebase/collaspe though, for someone inexperimented with mq like me :) Collapse also allows me to re-describe the new commit (but I guess this can be done with mq too).